# ffmpeg record video tape with audio

Tags: alsa, ffmpeg

I'm trying to record video tapes to digital, using this command:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 720x480 -i /dev/video2 -channel_layout stereo -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 2M -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128K -to 00:00:30 -preset fast -report tape1.mkv`

I get this error:

`[alsa @ 0x55ede20aa9e0] cannot open audio device hw:1,0 (Device or resource busy)
hw:1,0: Input/output error`

My VCR is plugged into a USB Recording Device.

`arecord -l` produces this:
`**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: CS4206 Analog [CS4206 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: USB20 [AV TO USB2.0], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

I'm not committed to using alsa. I just don't know what else to use to get this to work.

`fuser -fv /dev/snd/* /dev/dsp*`
Produces this:
`Specified filename /dev/dsp* does not exist.
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  matt      30999 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  matt      30999 F.... pulseaudio`

VLC can stream the input with audio if I pass this to it:
`v4l2:// :input-slave=alsa:// :v4l2-standard=0`
But I couldn't figure out how to pass that to ffmpeg.

I could possibly record these videotapes using VLC. But I would prefer to use ffmpeg to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the audio device as just `hw1`.

You can also try suspending Pulse:

```
pasuspender -- ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 720x480 -i /dev/video0 -channel_layout stereo -f alsa -i hw:1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 2M -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128K -to 00:00:30 -preset fast -report tape1.mkv
```